# follow all relationships but specific ones

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I tell cypher to NOT follow a certain relationship/edge?

E.g. I have a `:NODE` that is connected to another `:NODE` via a `:BUDDY` relationship. Additionally every `:NODE` is related to `:STUFF` in arbitrary depth by arbitrary edges which are **NOT** of type `:BUDDY`. I now want to add a shortcut relation from each `:NODE` to its `:STUFF`. However, I do not include `:STUFF` of its `:BUDDIES`.

```
(:NODE)-[:BUDDY]->(:NODE)

(:NODE)-[*]->(:STUFF)
```

My current query looks like this:

```
MATCH (n:Node)-[*]->(s:STUFF) WHERE NOT (n)-[:BUDDY]->()-[*]->(s) CREATE (n)-[:HAS]->(s)
```

However I have some issues with this query:

1) If I ever add a `:BUDDY` relationship not directly between `:NODE` but children of `:NODE` the query will use that relationship for matching. This might not be intended as I do not want to include buddies at all.

2) Explain tells me that neo4j does the match `(:NODE)-[*]->(:STUFF)` and then `AntiSemiApply` the pattern `(n)-[:BUDDY]->()`. As a result it matches the whole graph to then unmatch most of the found connections. This seems ineffective and the query runs slower than I like (However subjective this might sound).

One (bad) fix is to restrict the depth of `(:NODE)-[*]->(:STUFF)` via `(:NODE)-[*..XX]->(:STUFF)`. However, I cannot guarantee that depth unless I use a ridiculous high number for worst case scenarios.

I'd actually just like to tell neo4j to just not follow a certain relationship. E.g. `MATCH (n:NODE)-[ALLBUT(:BUDDY)*]->(s:STUFF) CREATE (n)-[:HAS]->(s)`. How can I achieve this without having to enumerate all allowed connections and connect them with a `|` (which is really fast - but I have to manually keep track of all possible relations)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution is generating a string from the set of

`{relations}\{relations_id_do_not_want}`

and use that for matching. As I am using an API and thus can do this generation automatically it is not as much as an inconvenience as I feared, but still an inconvenience. However, this was the only solution I was able to find since posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

One option for this particular schema is to explicitly traverse past the point where the `BUDDY` relationship is a concern, and then do all the unbounded traversing you like from there. Then you only have to apply the filter to single-step relationships:

```
MATCH (n:Node) -[r]-> (leaf)
WHERE NOT type(r) = 'BUDDY'
WITH n, leaf
MATCH (leaf) -[*] -> (s:Stuff)
WITH n, COLLECT(DISTINCT leaf) AS leaves, COLLECT(DISTINCT s) AS stuff
RETURN n, [leaf IN leaves WHERE leaf:Stuff] + stuff AS stuffs
```

The other option is to install `apoc` and take a look at the path expander procedure, which allows you to 'blacklist' node labels (such as :Node) from your path query, which may work just as well depending on your graph. [See here.](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths)

Comment: the solution is fine if I do not add `:BUDDY` relationships deeper in the graph. I will have a look at apoc.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a condition o nrelationship type:

```
MATCH (:Node)-[r:REL]->(:OtherNode)
WHERE NOT type(r) = 'your_unwanted_rel_type'
```

I have no clues about perf though